# How to make the edge of a button round with clip-path?

Tags: javascript, html, css, button, clip-path

How to make the edge of a button round with clip-path?

```css
.skew{
   border: none;
    background: none;
    outline: none;
    color: #fff;
    padding: 1rem 1.5rem;
    background-color: #ee128f;
    clip-path: polygon(0 0, 100% 0%, calc(100% - 22px) 100%, 0% 100%);
    margin: 1rem;
    border-radius: 5px;
    padding-right:3rem ; 
    /* border-bottom-right-radius: 5px; */
}
```

```html
 <button class="skew">text</button>
```

I tried `border-bottom-right-radius: 5px;` but it is not working well.

Comment: Are you asking how to make the bottom right of the button curved/round?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want all edges rounded, you can play with pseudo elements and `transform: skew` instead of `clip-path`.

```css
.skew{
    position: relative;
    border: none;
    background: none;
    outline: none;
    color: #fff;
    padding: 1rem 1.5rem;
    background-color: #ee128f;
    margin: 1rem;
    border-radius: 5px;
    padding-right:3rem ; 
}

.skew:after {
    content: " ";
    position: absolute;
    display: block;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    z-index: -1;
    background: #ee128f;
    border-radius: 5px;
    transform-origin: bottom left;
    -ms-transform: skew(-30deg, 0deg);
    -webkit-transform: skew(-30deg, 0deg);
    transform: skew(-30deg, 0deg);
}
```

```html
<button class="skew">text</button>
```